# Can the product of a complex symmetric unitary matrix and a skew-hermitian matrix be complex skew-symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, hermitian-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

- Let $S$ be a nonzero complex symmetric unitary matrix ($S\neq 0$, $S = S^T$, $S^HS=Id$)
- Let $B$ be a nonzero skew-hermitian matrix ($B\neq 0$, $B^H = -B$)

Can their product $P\triangleq SB$ be complex skew-symmetric ($P^T = -P$)? (I would say no)

Using the fact that $S = VV^T$ for a unitary $V$ and $B = UDU^H$ for a unitary $U$ and a purely imaginary diagonal matrix $D$, I could show that $P$ can be complex symmetric if $V = U^*$, but I could not show that it cannot be skew-symmetric.

Comment: When $S=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{i\\ &-i}$, $SB=\pmatrix{0&-i\\ i&0}$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot! More generally, for a given $B$, is it possible to determine a condition on $S$ (equivalently $V$) for $P$ to be skew-symmetric?

Comment: @user1551 , if $S$ and $B$ "anticommute" ($SB = -BS$) then $P$ is skew-symmetric if $B$ is complex symmetric (which is the case in your example). Now, if this is not the case (for example if $B$ has a nonzero real part and is thus not complex symmetric anymore), can $P$ be skew-symmetric?

Answer (score 0):

Since $B$ is skew-Hermitian, it can be written as $K+iH$ for some real skew-symmetric matrix $K$ and real symmetric matrix $H$. The condition that $(SB)^T=-SB$ is therefore equivalent to $KS=SK$ and $HS=-SH$. It should be easy to construct a feasible solution $(K,H,S)$. Consider e.g.
$$
K=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&0\\ &&0&-1\\ &&1&0},\ 
H=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1\\ &&0&0\\ &&0&0},\ 
S=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0\\ &&1&0\\ &&0&1}.
$$